# Decode all values in a categorical column of pandas data-frame by a specific rule

Tags: python, pandas

[image: decode categorical data]

Only B and D values are to be decoded as 0; rest of the values would be decoded as 1.

A set of values are decoded as 0 and rest of the values are decoded as 1; may be a binary decoding.

Comment: @not_speshal please help on this

Comment: please provide the input data as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
df['pulse'] = (~df['fault_code'].isin(['B', 'D'])).astype(int)
```

or taking advantage of boolean -> int equivalence:

```
df['pulse'] = df['fault_code'].isin(['B', 'D']).rsub(1)
```

output:

*no output as no text data was provided*